# Sub-graph Selection Algorithm Problem (Dynamic Programming or NP)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, np-complete, dynamic-programming

We have an algorithm problem in hand, can you please write your ideas about this, thank you!

There are N many nodes with K different colors. Some of the nodes have direct connection between each other and some do not. We want to select M nodes from these N total nodes, but these M nodes must be connected. Also, our selected group of M nodes must have minimum number of distinct colored neighbors. There might be more than one best combinations, finding any of them is the goal.

For example, we selected M nodes and in total, these M nodes have the following neighbors: 5 red, 3 blue, 1 green. In this case, we count the unique colors, so the number of distinct colored neighbors, in this case, is 3. We want to minimize this number by selecting the best possible combination of M nodes.

[Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3k9M.png)

In this example, let's assume M = 4, then the best possible combination of nodes would be {9, 10, 11, 12} since this group has only one neighbor which is yellow. If we choose {0, 1, 3, 5}, the neighbors of this combination would be {2, 4, 6}, which consists of 2 red neighbors and 1 green neighbor; which results with score of 2 since we look for distinct number of colored neighbors.

Is this algorithm question NP-complete? How should we proceed? If this is not NP-complete, what is the best algorithm we can use to solve this problem? Can we combine graph algorithms such as Prim’s, Kruskal's, Floyd Warshall or traversal algorithms?